# How can I vertically center all children of my div using css?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code

```css
.header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background: black;
    }
    
    .header .headerContainer {
        position: relative;
     top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        height: inherit;
    }
    
    img#logo {
        height: 75%;    
    }
    
    p#logotext {
        color: white;
        display: inline
    }
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerContainer">
        <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/react.svg" alt="Logo" id="logo" />
        <p id="logotext">Welcome To Here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, this is not aligning the elements properly.

How should I modify my CSS so that `headerContainer` does the alignment properly?

Comment: Inline does not center elements vertically. It puts the elements side by side.

Comment: the top and transform do vertically align though, when I attach them to individual elements. But when I attach them to the container, they stop working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flexbox to solve this:

```css
.header {
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.header .headerContainer {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: inherit;
}
img#logo {
  height: 75%;    
}
p#logotext {
  color: white;
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerContainer">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Logo" id="logo" />
        <p id="logotext">Welcome To Here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So you don't need to use `position` or `tranform` to vertical center the items. If you want to learn more about flexbox I recommend [this site](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a quick overview / reference.

Comment: @AyushGupta check this out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @AyushGupta I'd also recommend looking into CSS Grid. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code

```
<style>
.class{
Position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:rotateX(-50%,50%);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS Grid.

```css
.header {
  background: black;
  height: 100%
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
.header .headerContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
img#logo {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  align-self: center;
}

p#logotext {
  color: white;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerContainer">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Logo" id="logo" />
        <p id="logotext">Welcome To Here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: css grid support isnt there in older versions of browsers though

Comment: True. IE11+ supports it though. https://caniuse.com/#search=grid. You can also see on average, most people are on modern browsers (https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php)

Answer (score 0):

so close .... you just need to put dispaly : flex; into headerContainer

```css
.header {
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.header .headerContainer {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: inherit;
}
img#logo {
  height: 75%;    
}
p#logotext {
  color: white;
  display: inline
}
```